# How to dynamically create multiple form input fields with incremented ng-models?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After reading [this article](http://mrngoitall.net/blog/2013/10/02/adding-form-fields-dynamically-in-angularjs/), I understand how to dynamically add a form field using `ng-repeat`.

I am wondering how can multiple form elements be dynamically created with incrementing `ng-model` values.

For example, the following would be created from a button click.

```
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar1.first">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar1.second">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar1.third">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar1.fourth">

<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar2.first">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar2.second">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar2.third">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar2.fourth">

<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar3.first">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar3.second">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar3.third">
<input ng-model="vm.foo.bar3.fourth">
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to restructure your ViewModel to make `vm.foo.bar` an array. Then this would be trivial:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in barItems">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo.bar[$index].first">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo.bar[$index].second">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo.bar[$index].third">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo.bar[$index].fourth">
</div>
```

Or, if you insist, then also

```
<div ng-repeat="item in barItems" ng-init="outerIdx = $index">
   <input ng-repeat='p in ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]' 
          ng-model="vm.foo.bar[outerIdx][p]">
</div>
```

(I'm assuming here, that unlike with `first`, `second`, etc..., the number of `bar`s is not known - hence an array is a better option)

**EDIT**:

If you really want, you could also make `vm.foo` an object that holds properties `bar1`, `bar2`, etc...:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo['bar' + item].first">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo['bar' + item].second">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo['bar' + item].third">
  <input ng-model="vm.foo['bar' + item].fourth">
</div>
```

but don't forget to first create `vm.foo` object in the controller:

```
this.foo = {};
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer.  In my case, vm was set to `this` in the controller to replace `$scope`.

Answer (score 1):

When I have to do this I use the $index to control the names of things. Although I've never tried this exact code, this should work.

```
<input ng-model='vm.foo.bar3[$index]'></input>
```

$index comes along whenever you do ng-repeat and is just the index of the list item. So that should end up making ng-models that are vm.foo.bar3.0 to whatever.

Answer (score 0):

To my point of view, you should create arrays of models in your controller.

```
$scope.vm.foo = [{
    bar1: [{
        first: '',
        second: '',
        ...
       },
    bar2: ...
  ],
}]
```

And then in your view iterate on your tab :

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in foo">
    <div ng-repeat="input in elem">
        <input ng-model="input">
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help you !